# Hbase Table from HBase query

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

Is there anyway we can create a Hbase table as an output of hbase query? Suppose I have a huge hbase table and then I query the hbase table using filter. I want to store the result back into Hbase table. Is it possible?

Comment: So the result of the first table should be store in a new hbase table - and all this thin should be done in single shot?

Comment: @Ramzy Yes.. I want to store the result into another Hbase table. Or a HFile. Not necessarily in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can take snapshot of your running Hbase table and export it to the HDFS .
Write Mapreduce to get data as you want in a file and then Bulk Load to new Hbase table .
You can directly write data into Hbase table also .
In that way running MapReduce on Snapshot will not impact the actual Hbase table also .
This is how you can do all steps are mentioned below

Create snapshot

```
snapshot 'HbaseTable','HbaseTableSnapshot'
```

Export Snapshot to local hdfs

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot HbaseTableSnapshot-copy-to /tmp -mappers 16
```

Driver Job Configuration to rum mapreduce on Hbase snapshot

```
    String snapshotName="HbaseTableSnapshot";
    Path restoreDir = new Path("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp");
    String  hbaseRootDir =  "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase";

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableSnapshotMapperJob(snapshotName, // Snapshot name
                    scan, // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
                    DefaultMapper.class, // mapper class
                    NullWritable.class, // mapper output key
                    Text.class, // mapper output value
                    job,
                    true,
                    restoreDir);
```

Also running mapreduce on Hbase snapshot will skip scan on Hbase table and also there will be no impact on region server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hbase as source and sink for a map reduce. I hope [this](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html) will help you. refer to 7.2.4 section. Since you will be writing put as output in parallel, the time is also optimized.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But my requirement is something where I can query the hbase table with a particular version for the columns, and then store the results into a hbase table.

Comment: OK, what is stopping you from setting maximum versions to the scan, for the first table. You can use, scan.setmaxVersions() and get all versions.

Comment: The requirement is that i need to select one particular version from the table and then query it via hive. So i need to store the result back to hbase table in order to query via hive

Answer (score 0):

You can write a job to read from the 1st table as keyValue pairs and then persist it in the 2nd table.

If you are concerned about the performance? then u can write a map reduce job to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly query hbase and create another table in it which contains your output but you can write map reduce to do the same. Apart from map reduce, if you would use Apache Phoenix over your hbase to do so, you will be able to write a query to select the data and store it into hbase table.

Answer (score 0):

Clever and nice Idea...

You could accomplish this using HappyBase which is a python front-End we use in our production services.

However if you are literally talking of 100 Million plus return values - I would not recommend this. Up to 10-20 Million records you get a good throughput (we average 8k records per second insert. Apron 0.5M/min ).